How to create app.module.ts in an existing Angular 18 project?
I’m using Angular 18.2.8 and I’ve already created a project and worked on it. However, I noticed that the project does not include an app.module.ts file. After searching, I found that starting from Angular 17, the default structure might not include this file due to the introduction of standalone components.
However, I want to transition to the traditional module-based structure (with app.module.ts). Is there a way to generate an app.module.ts file in Angular 18 using Angular CLI? Or do I need to manually create and configure it?
I have tried this command : ng new --no-standalone
But got : Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI inside a workspace.

you could try ng g app my-app --standalone=false. but standalone way is considered a modern one as it reduces the boilerplate, simplifies the injector tree understanding and libraries optimize themselves for standalone approach

Thanks, but this dose not work with already exists project. I’d like to modify my existing Angular project to include an app.module.ts using Angular CLI. However, it seems the only options are to either create the app.module.ts manually or recreate the project with the --standalone=false option from the start.

there is no automatic migration for your case, but you can create a project skeleton with that command and move most of the logic for an existing standalone app

Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI inside a workspace.

This error shows when you run ng new inside an existing angular project.
However:
-> If you are trying to create a new project without standalones run:

ng new <project-name> --standalone=false outside your existing angular project.


run ng new <project-name> --help for more details.

-> Also you have the option to generate a new application within your existing workspace if you want to adapt a monorepo architecture then you can run:
ng g app --standalone=false
